# Kappa function in infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, infinity

I saw a greek letter in an infinite series, and found out it was Kappa. What does this do? It looks like a giant K.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+continued+fraction+of+square+root

That's where i found it.

Comment: Did you see the little footnote at the end of your link, that next to the $K_{k=k_1}^{k_2}a_k/b_k$ has its definition? The $K$ is just shorthand for the continued-fraction operation, just as $\Sigma$ is shorthand for sum and $\Pi$ is for product.

Comment: thank you very much...i missed that

Comment: I guess $K$ comes from the Greek word κλάσμα=fraction.

Comment: ooh that was helpful too - you're greek? awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the notation for a Generalized Continued Fraction.
$$ \mathrm{K}_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{b_k} = \frac{a_0}{b_0 + \frac{a_1}{b_1 + \frac{a_2}{b_2 + \ddots}}}$$

See that?  The numerators in the $K$ notation, in this case $a_k$, denotes the numerators on each branch of a continued fraction.  The denominator in the $K$ notation, in this case $b_k$, denotes the addend adjacent to the the next iteration of the fraction.

I hope that makes sense to you and helps. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to make a capital Kappa Κ in latex.